# Adding a new field to OpportunityLineItemSchedule

Tags: custom-field, opp-lineitemschedule

We have a requirement to add some extra functionality around schedules. Is there a way to extend this object with a custom field? I can't find it in the Salesforce setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Salesforce support and they said it's not possible to extend OpportunityLineItemSchedule.

Answer (score 4):

We had to work on a similar requirement once. Instead of working with the OpportunityLineItemSchedule object, we needed similar extensions on collaborationGroup object. Since the object was not exposed in the setup, we had to go around with an alternative which might be helpful in this case. Though it's not the most elegant solution.

We created a custom object which had all the fields as the collaborationGroup object along with the new fields that we wanted. We used this new object to handle all our functionality. In the backend since we still wanted the chatter group, we created a trigger that created a new group whenever a new record was created in this new object.

Maybe you could employ a similar technique in your solution. Hope this helps.